# Delay report to after write

Tags: reporting-services, timedelay

I am using SSRS to update a table.  I have a series of parameters which the user will select from header prior to running the report.  The report is run after a stored procedure is executed to update the table.  My problem is that in some cases, not all, the write will occur but the report will display no results.  I can check the table and the information is correctly updated.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to delay the report until after the write in the stored procedure.

Here is the stored procedure that is called:

```
USE [InvoiceSHC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MasterDataUpdate]    Script Date: 01/25/2013 14:07:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Tim Vavra
-- Create date: 1/15/2013
-- Description: This procedure is designed to update the table MasterData 
-- with information entered into SSRS report by Production Assistants.
-- this information will be used to create the invoice for SHC and provide metric 
-- information.
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MasterDataUpdate]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @Ref float,
    @Phase nvarchar(255),
    @Page nvarchar(255),
    @PageType nvarchar(255),
    @Percent int,
    @ChangeType nvarchar(255),
    @UserName varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Insert into MasterData 
    (Ad,Page,[Page Type],[Percent],Phase,[Change Type],LstChng, [UID])

    values( @Ref, @Page, @PageType, @Percent, @Phase, @ChangeType, GETDATE(), @UserName)

end

    update MasterData
    set [Base Page] =
        Case 
            When [Page] like '[1-99]' then [Page]
            When [Page] like '%[A-Z]' then left([Page],1)+((ASCII(convert(varchar,(RIGHT([Page],1))))-64)*.01)
            When[Page] like '%-%' then LEFT([Page],1)+(cast(RIGHT([page],2)as int)*.01)+.26

end         

    update MasterData 
    set [Alt Type] =
        Case
            When [Page] like '[1-99]' then 'B'
            When [Page] like '%[A-Z]' then 'A'
            When[Page] like '%-%' then 'T'


END
```

Here is the query for the dataset I use in the report:

```
SELECT     MasterData.Ad, MasterData.Page, MasterData.[Page Type], MasterData.[Percent], MasterData.Phase, MasterData.[Change Type], MasterData.LstChng, 
                  PageCost.Amt AS PageCost, VersionCost.Amt AS VersionCost
FROM         MasterData INNER JOIN
                      PageCost ON MasterData.[Page Type] = PageCost.PageType INNER JOIN
                      VersionCost ON MasterData.[Change Type] = VersionCost.ChangeType
WHERE     (MasterData.Ad = @Ref) AND (MasterData.Phase = @Phase) AND (MasterData.Page = @Page)
```

I hope this is enough information to help someone provide a solution.

Comment: The first thing would be to see if the problem is actually that there is no data. SSRS or something else in the code may be failing or causing the blank report and it has nothing or to do with the timing or data being in the table.

Answer (score 0):

For my answer to work you must ensure you have a legitimate SSRS Server hosting your reports to gain access to it's features on it's web service.

Data driven subscription could send out the report to a format based on a criteria.  You could set a job up to update the code, possibly store the data of the last successful run in a database table, query that output happened to generate the report.  Here is the MSDN article on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89197b9b-7502-4fe2-bea3-ed7943eebf3b#bkmk_startwizard

A simpler approach may be to set up a standard subscription on a daily increment that occurs after a nightly job when both are set to a static time.

Honestly both approaches may work for you but the first one is going to take more time to set up but will be more flexible.  The second approach is more ingrained but far easier to set up and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest o create a function that returns a `ref_cursor`of your `MasterData` table after it executes the procedure. My work has many of these to capture historic values.